# Switching from Oracle 10g Express to SQL Server Compact (NHibernate)

Tags: sql, nhibernate, oracle10g, sql-server-ce

Hey, I am switching my application from Oracle 10g to SQL Server Compact.  Currently I have this in the mapping file:

```
<id name="Id" column="MY_ID">
  <generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">MY_SEQ</param>
  </generator>
</id>
```

and I have been informed that sequence does not exist in SQL Server Compact, I was wondering if there was an equivalent. Also I was wondering if I switch to SQL Server 2000/2005 if there is an equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options here:

**GUID**:

```
<id name="Id" column="MY_ID">
      <generator class="guid" />
</id>
```

**Integral-type identities**:

```
<id name="Id" column="MY_ID" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity"/>
</id>
```

**Native**, i.e. identity, sequence or hilo depending upon the capabilities of the underlying database:

```
<id name="Id" column="MY_ID" type="Int32">
      <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

---

More information::

- [**Understanding Hibernate 'generator' element**](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernateidgeneratorelement.shtml)
- [**Avoid identity generator when possible**](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-avoid-identity-generator-when-possible.aspx)